# "mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given" error

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>All</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include ("connection.php");

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM student_data") or die('Query failed');

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array('$result'))
  {
  echo $row['name'];
  echo $row['fname'];
  echo $row['sid'];
  echo $row['email'];
  echo "<br>";
  }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This i suppose to print every data in the database. But i get the following error. Where am i going wrong? [image]

Comment: Variables under single quotes **will not be parsed**. `mysqli_fetch_array($result))`

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger — Even if they were, it would still be a string and not a result object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysqli\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli\_result, boolean given in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439919/mysqli-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-result-boolean-given-in)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove apostrophe around `$result`. This `mysqli_fetch_array('$result')` should be `mysqli_fetch_array($result)`

Note the difference:

`'$result'` is a string (single apostrophe)

`$result` is a resource returned by `mysqli_query`

Answer (score 1):

The error message complains that you are passing it a string instead of a result.

You have quotes around `'$result'`. That makes it a string. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Replcae the following line

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array('$result'))
```

with this one `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))`

Answer (score 0):

when `'$result'` or `"$result"` is used php will read it as a text string.
In your issue it needs to be a php variable.