# Fetching data error relational tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve some data from my database where I have a join in place. I have 3 tables:

users column=user_id
cats column=cat_id
user_cat_join columns-user_is & cat_id

The user_cat_join table are related to to the corresponding tables.

I am trying to get the data out the table to only show the categories assigned to the user I am logged in as. So, I am getting the users ID from the session function and then trying to draw out the data I require.

require ('../db_con.php');

```
// BUILD AND DISPLAY THE CATEGORY LIST (RICOH BUILD)

function build_cat_list()
{

    global $dbc;

    // DEFINE THE QUERY:
    $user = $_SESSION['user'];
    $q = "SELECT cat_name, cat_icon, cat_color
                                FROM cats
                                INNER JOIN user_cat_join
                                ON cats.cat_id = user_cat_join.cat_id
                                WHERE user_cat_join.user_id = $user"; 
    $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the query.


    // FETCH AND PRINT ALL THE RECORDS
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
    echo '

    <a href="view_cat.php?cat_id='.$row["cat_id"].'">
        <div class="indexBox"">
            <div class="indexBoxHeader"  style="background-color:'.$row["cat_color"].'"><p>'
                .$row["cat_icon"].'</p>
                </div>
            <div class="indexBoxFooter">
                <p>'.$row["cat_name"].'</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>';

    }
}
```

when displaying this I get the following error?

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\MAMP\htdocs\home.php on line 33
```

The above is referencing this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
```

I have done somre further error reporting and by doing this:

```
if($r === FALSE) { 
     printf(mysqli_error($dbc));
    exit();
}
```

I get this:

> Unknown column '5ad3e66c5e1e7747707c480dca04fc85' in 'where clause'

I have no idea where that is referring to?

**UPDATE**

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');

    // BUILD AND DISPLAY THE CATEGORY LIST (RICOH BUILD)

    global $dbc;

    // DEFINE THE QUERY:
    $user = $_SESSION['user'];

    $q = sprintf("
        SELECT
            cat_name, cat_icon, cat_color
        FROM
            cats
        INNER JOIN
            user_cat_join
        ON
            cats.cat_id = user_cat_join.cat_id
        WHERE
            user_cat_join.user_id = '%s'
        ",
        mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $user)
        );


     $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the query.

    if($r === FALSE) { 
        printf(mysqli_error($dbc));

    }  


    // FETCH AND PRINT ALL THE RECORDS
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {

       var_dump($row);

    echo '
    <a href="view_cat.php?cat_id='.$row["cat_id"].'">
        <div class="indexBox"">
            <div class="indexBoxHeader"  style="background-color:'.$row["cat_color"].'"><p>'
                .$row["cat_icon"].'</p>
                </div>
            <div class="indexBoxFooter">
                <p>'.$row["cat_name"].'</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>';

    }
?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439919/mysqli-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-result-boolean-given-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't your `WHERE` be like below, otherwise your current `WHERE` clause looks like `WHERE user_cat_join.user_id = 5ad3e66c5e1e7747707c480dca04fc85`; which your DB engine thinking is a separate column and so complaining about the same.

```
WHERE user_cat_join.user_id ='". $user. "'"
```

In short it should looks like

```
$q = "SELECT cat_name, cat_icon, cat_color
                            FROM cats
                            INNER JOIN user_cat_join
                            ON cats.cat_id = user_cat_join.cat_id
                            WHERE user_cat_join.user_id ='". $user. "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to quote your user variable:

```
$q = "SELECT cat_name, cat_icon, cat_color
                            FROM cats
                            INNER JOIN user_cat_join
                            ON cats.cat_id = user_cat_join.cat_id
                            WHERE user_cat_join.user_id = '$user'";
```

Comment: Hey I still get `Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\MAMP\htdocs\home.php on line 331 back at me

Comment: Is the error "Unknown column '5ad3e66c5e1e7747707c480dca04fc85' in 'where clause'" still the same?

Comment: I am just getting a blank screen now with no errors and errors set to on.

Comment: Try to print the query now, so you can see how it looks like. Seems like the query now has the correct syntax, but does not have any resulting rows.

Comment: Still getting nothing, I will post my code up in my question