# PHP error: Why isn’t this working, I can't see data result in my page?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'am setting up a new wampserver and created a new database with a table named 'users'

apache 2.4.23 & PHP 7.1.10 & mySQL 5.7.14

```
<?php

    $server = 'localhost';
    $serverUsername = 'root';
    $serverPassword = '';
    $dbName = 'test';

    $connection = mysqli_connect($server,$serverUsername,$serverPassword);
    msqli_select_db($dbName);
    if(!$connection){
        echo 'connection failed to database '.mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $query = mysqli_query($sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        print_r($row);
    }

?>
```

my value is really in th data base but nothing appears in the page after running code

Comment: Show us the code you're using to retrieve this data. We can't help you if we don't know what it is you're doing.

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments, instead, edit your question and paste it there. Thanks. Also, here's a link to [the documentation of mysqli_query()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), you're missing the `$link`(`$connection`)

Comment: move your `$dbName` as a 4th parameter when `mysqli_connect` and remove `msqli_select_db` line (becasue it is not necessary and has typo)

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function msqli_select_db() in C:\wamp64\www\mysql\select_mysql.php on line 9

( ! ) Error: Call to undefined function msqli_select_db() in C:\wamp64\www\mysql\select_mysql.php on line 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the comments mentioning the fix

```
$server = 'localhost';
$serverUsername = 'root';
$serverPassword = '';
$dbName = 'test';

// FIX 1
// You need to mention the database name as the last argument
$connection = mysqli_connect($server,$serverUsername,$serverPassword, $dbName);
if(!$connection){
    echo 'connection failed to database '.mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";

// FIX 2
// The first argument should be your mysqli connection
$query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

// Check for errors
if (!$query) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($connection));
    exit();
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    print_r($row);
}

?>
```

Reference for `mysqli_connect`: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Reference for `mysqli_query`: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp64\www\mysql\select_mysql.php on line 18

Comment: @MegaEn That means your query is wrong. Does the **users** table exist in the given database?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/14578644/7362396 for how to make mysqli automatically escalate errors in your queries, so you get a better hint.

Comment: Adding to @TobiasK. reference, here's another one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15440076/2736770 which will help you find the error

Comment: @MegaEn I have updated my answer to check for errors, try it and see if there's a better error message

Comment: @ShahlinIbrahim
thank you ibrahim it works well
can i know what you changed

Comment: @MegaEn Other than the fixes I've mentioned in the code, I added the if statement below the `$query` variable that provides you clear error message. [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15440076/2736770)